# How do I make an efficiënt look up on 160million rows in a DataFrame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a big table and I'm wondering how to do an efficiënt look up.

```
df = 
|Date      |zipcode|number|letter|
|2023-06-01|123456A| 1    |a     |
|2023-03-01|123456A| 1    |a     |
|2023-06-01|123216B| 1    |      |
|2023-06-01|123456A| 1    |      |
|2023-03-01|123456C| 1    |      |
|2023-06-01|123216B| 15   |      |
|2023-06-01|123456A| 13   |      |
|2023-03-01|123456C| 11   |      |
|2023-06-01|123216B| 1    |b     |
```

I get an API call with this parameter date = "2023-06-01" and this json:
{{zipcode: "123456A", number: 1, letter: "a"}, {zipcode"123216B", number: 1, letter: "b"}}

What's the most efficient way to look things up?
Since the best split would be over date I made a dictionary with the date as a key and the rest of the table as a value.

But now I still have to look up different zipcodes, number, letter combinations. I can't imagine that the fastest would be something like

```
output = pd.Dataframe([])
for zipcode, number, letter in json_input:
    output.append(df[(df.zipcode==zipcode) & (df.number==number) & (df.letter==letter)])
```

There is no correlation in zipcode/number/letter. Any to improve look up speed?

Comment: Can you pass arguments to the API call to filter before you receive the response?

Comment: 160 million rows is a lot for pandas. Are you even able to fit your dataset into memory?

Comment: @Avantgarde To be honest, I didn't try yet. It's on a database server and I could query based on that. But so far that looks slower than locally saving a parquet/feather/pickle file and reading that in.

Comment: @Stitt: I could but as I mentioned above as well. It looks slower to run a query than to saved the whole file locally.

Comment: @Hestaron: my approach would be create a list of unique day (or) zip code from the Json. Then create a sub dataframe has those key rather than lookup over again the 160 millions rows